# Android strange list selector behaviour

Tags: android, android-listview, android-selector

I have a list where the list items have 2 clickable icon inside. The problem is that on Android 2.3 to Android 4.0.3 when I press a list item not only the row gets highlighted but also the icons are highlighted, but on Android > 4.1 this is not the case, here it works like it should, only the row gets highlighted.

The selector of my list:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />    
<item android:state_focused="true"    android:state_enabled="false"  android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"    android:state_enabled="false"                                android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />    
<item android:state_focused="true"                                   android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/dna_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />    
<item android:state_focused="false"                                  android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/dna_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />      
<item android:state_focused="true"                                                                 android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_holo" />    
<item android:state_activated="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/list_longpressed_holo" />
```

And this is the selector of the icons:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />    
<item android:state_focused="true"    android:state_enabled="false"  android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"    android:state_enabled="false"                                android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />    
<item android:state_focused="true"                                   android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/dna_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />    
<item android:state_focused="false"                                  android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/dna_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />      
<item android:state_focused="true"                                                                 android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_holo" />
```

I already searched a lot and tried to find out the problem but I am not getting it. Was the beheviour changed on Android 4.1?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that till exclusive android 4.1 the pressed state is also given to the children of the root list view and seeing that I defined following:

```
<item android:state_focused="false" 
     android:state_pressed="true" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/dna_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />
```

the icons in the list item is till android 4.1 pressed but not focused. I don't know if this is a bug or designed so, but it doesn't make sanse for me that the children also get the pressed state.
Starting with Android 4.1 the icons in the list item doesn't get the pressed state anymore.

Solution was to change the above selector to:

```
<item android:state_focused="false"   
      android:state_pressed="true"  
      android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```